# nm: shared library symbol appearing twice or once

Tags: c#, c, shared-libraries, artoolkit, nm

I have a shared library (*libARWrapper.so*) which includes the following two entries, shown using nm (*nm -D --defined-only libARWrapper.so*)

```
00075854 T Java_org_artoolkit_ar_base_NativeInterface_arwAcceptVideoImage
00074d54 T Java_org_artoolkit_ar_base_NativeInterface_arwCapture
...
00072d54 T arwCapture
```

I know that [T means](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) "The symbol is in the text (code) section."

**What is the distinction between arwCapture appearing twice, and arwAcceptVideoImage, which appears only once.**

I am able to call *arwCapture* from a C# DllImport, but not *arwAcceptVideoImage*.
There are also many other functions appearing the same as arwCapture, all under org.artoolkit.ar.bash.NativeInterface, which I can use OK.
Other (Java) code is able to call all functions through the NDK.

Comment: Just because something is stored in the text segment doesn't automatically mean it's a function or some code. Compile-time constants usually also end up in the text segment, as does e.g. string literals.

Comment: I don't see any symbols here appearing twice. `Java_org_artoolkit_ar_base_NativeInterface_arwCapture` and `arwCapture` are two wildly different symbols. The output does not mention any `arwAcceptVideoImage` symbol, so it's quite natural you cannot call it,

Comment: Thanks, so the distinction is the ones that appear twice are defined as both functions and JNI calls, but the one that appears once is only defined as a JNI call.  Makes sense now, thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the posted output from `nm` there is no evidence of what you state (*`arwCapture()` does not appear twice*). One is the JNI function which is surely a wrapper that calls `arwCapture()` at some point.

Presumably `arwCapture()` is a c function which is why you can call it from C#, but in the shared object, there is no `arwAcceptVideoImage()` anywhere although there is a Java `arwAcceptVideoImage()` method defined.

If this shared object is intended as a JNI object, you should avoid calling it from another language but Java. Instead find the original library and use it.